# remove a check on a duplication of the tarif

Tags: acumatica

I would like to know if it is possible via code to remove this control?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation is executed in `CheckForDuplicateDetails` method.
You can override the method.
Make sure there is no bad side effects down the line if you remove this validation.

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APPriceWorksheetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPriceWorksheetMaint>
  {
    public delegate void CheckForDuplicateDetailsDelegate();

    [PXOverride]
    public void CheckForDuplicateDetails(CheckForDuplicateDetailsDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      // To skip validation, don't call base method
      // baseMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Au top ! Merci beaucoup Hugues !